# Underline html text in python

Tags: python, html, formatting

How can I write an html text in python which is underlined

For instance, I am trying to create an underlined header as follows:

```
html.h3('I WANT TO SHOW THIS TEXT UNDERLINED'),
```

any clues?

Comment: This question shows very little research effort. Maybe you could tell us what you tried already?

Comment: Thanks emsimpson, below Simon gave me the clue for this. html.H3(children = 'I WANT TO SHOW THIS TEXT UNDERLINED', style ={ 'text-decoration':'underline'})

Comment: What package are you using for `html.h3`? It may include a method to provide underline functionality.

Comment: dash_html_components,  it works beautiful :)

Answer (score 1):

Since underlining in HTML can be applied with `text-decoration:underline` then just put your text between tags by using `format()` or newer `f-strings`:

```
>>> a = 'I WANT TO SHOW THIS TEXT UNDERLINED'
>>> b = '<span style="text-decoration:underline">{}</span>'.format(a)
>>>print(b)
<span style="text-decoration:underline">I WANT TO SHOW THIS TEXT UNDERLINED</span>
>>>
```

Or even better  you could use an external css script:

**styles.css:**

```
h3 {
    text-decoration:underline;
}
```

And just insert it between the `<head></head>` tags.

Comment: Thanks Simon!!!! your answer helped me to figure this out. I did this by using html.H3(children = 'I WANT TO SHOW THIS TEXT UNDERLINED',
                style ={ 'text-decoration':'underline'})